# Requiring self signed certificate when referencing the Twilio dll

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2017, twilio, strong-named-key

I am trying to integrate with Twilio to send text messages from our application. I did the nuget install as instructed on their site. When I attempt to run anything that references the dll, I'm getting this message:

[image]

[image]

I unchecked the `Sign the Assembly` in the project and that fixed this but I don't have the liberty of changing the project file.

[image]

How do I get around this without having to uncheck this option?

Comment: As far as I know, if you want to reference the library directly (and not through another proxy/wrapper) the only thing you can do is compile a signed version [of the source code](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-csharp) yourself.

Comment: @VisualVincentty for the info, I'm trying that now.

Comment: @VisualVincent that worked perfectly after a few adjustments. If you want to put that as an answer, I will give you an upvote!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to reference the library directly (not through another proxy/wrapper) the easiest fix in this scenario would be to [download the source code](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-csharp) and compile a signed version yourself.

However, I stumbled upon this interesting article: [.NET-Fu: Zero Delay Signing Of An Unsigned Assembly](https://dzone.com/articles/net-fu-zero-delay-signing-of-a), and contrary to my initial comment, it seems you can actually sign an already compiled DLL by first decompiling it into [IL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Intermediate_Language) and then recompiling it, signing it in the process. Microsoft even provides you with tools that can be used to do so, namely *ildasm* for decompilation and *ilasm* for re-compilation.

Comment: tyvm for your help!

Comment: @ErocM : No problem. Glad I could be of help! Good luck with your project!